# Why does the ReceiveMessageAsync Method in AWS SQS .net SDK crash my application?

Tags: c#, amazon-sqs

I have written a console application in C# to pull all messages from an AWS SQS queue.  For some reason, when my code hits the ReceiveMessageAsync function, my application just quits, no error message or anything.

Here is my code:

```
        var attributeNames = new List<string>() { "All" };
        int maxNumberOfMessages = 50;
        var visibilityTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds;
        var waitTimeSeconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds;

        try
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json",
                                                                 optional: false,
                                                                 reloadOnChange: true);
            var options = builder.Build().GetAWSOptions();
            var sqsClient = options.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonSQS>();

            var request = new ReceiveMessageRequest
            {
                QueueUrl = queueUrl,
                AttributeNames = attributeNames,
                MaxNumberOfMessages = maxNumberOfMessages,
                VisibilityTimeout = visibilityTimeout,
                WaitTimeSeconds = waitTimeSeconds,
            };

            var response = await sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(request);
            
            if (response.Messages.Count > 0)
            {
                ProcessMessages(response.Messages);
            }
        }
```

I did make sure that the IAM user from where the client key was generated has access to the queue.  Am I missing something?

I have tried several different ways of authenticating with the same results.

Comment: What do you have after `try { ... }`? Do you have a `finally` clause? or a `catch` clause? Please show us what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the SQS client, not the actual request. There is an example application in the [Code Library here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sqs_example_sqs_ReceiveMessage_section.html) that includes a console application that uses ReceiveMessageAsync. You could try it and see if it works with your Queue. [GitHub link is here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/SQS#code-examples) to download the example.